# Select URL for copying in mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, mobile-chrome

I've been trying around for some time and searched and searched for solutions with no results so far.

The problem:

I have an URL in a webpage that I want to select as a whole to copy it from a mobile browser.
For Firefox I'm using a readonly input of type text and with the click event listener I trigger select() on the input. That works like a charm on mobile FF.

For Safari there also is a workaround which even triggers the copy-dialog on click.

With Chrome I could not manage to achieve this.

There is a Chrome issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=251235) which says that selecting from an input wich is readonly does not work (thats still true, tested that).

By using a Label:

```
<label id="fileLink" type="text" class="link fakeInput" />
```

, a method to select the text from [here](http://aktuell.de.selfhtml.org/artikel/javascript/textauswahl/) and

```
$('#fileLink').click(function() { markieren(this) });
```

, I was able to select the url with a click on it. But this will not trigger the copy-dialog. By holding onto the url to copy it, it will only select a part of it and then I have to manually select the whole url to copy it.

I can't imagine, that there is no workaround for this.

To be more clear: for FF I'm using in javascript:

```
$('#pFileLink').append('<input id="fileLink" type="text" class="link" readonly="readonly" />');
$('#fileLink').click(function() { this.select(); });
$('#fileLink').val(url)
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this for mobile chrome?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "will not trigger the copy-dialog"? You can't access the clipboard in Chrome so far.

You can alert the link, use a promp or a "modal box" with a input type text (not readonly) with selected text so the user can copy it.